# Confused by SQL Server Express when create a new database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I am an administrator of of my own machine, I have SQL Server Express installed. But when I tried to create a new database I got this error

> Create Database permission denied in database  'master'

[image]

I figured I was missing 'sysadmin' role for my login. When I tried to add my self as 'sysadmin' I got another error

> User does not have permission to perform this action

[image]

I am the administrator of this machine, why cannot I have permission to create a new database in this SQL Server Express instance?

Thanks

Comment: Youre using MYDOMAIN\SQLEXPRESS database type DatabaseEngine with windows authentication?

Comment: Did you add **yourself** to the sysadmins during install??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2010/02/23/how-to-take-ownership-of-your-local-sql-server-2008-express.aspx) may be helpful as well. It points to a script that allows you to add yourself to sysadmin role (provided that you are a local Windows admin).

**Update** As the link to the actual script is gone, refer to the StackExchange answer on [how to take ownership of a SQL Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/182430/taking-sql-server-database-ownership-after-the-original-owner-has-left-the-compa).

Comment: How awesome it is, my friend!

Comment: ah yes. Very good. I guess I'm spoiled having the admin also being the sysadmin. Never would have thought of that and hopefully when I'm in a less hospitable environment, I will remember this.

Comment: While running the script in the post, make sure that you are not logged in to the SQL Server instance. The first time I ran it, I was logged and the script failed. I logged out and ran it again, it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at this post. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dparys/archive/2009/09/17/create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master-my-fix.aspx

There are system level rights and then there are SQL rights, sometimes they don't align.

Comment: tried " CREATE LOGIN [your domain account] FROM WINDOWS;" got 

error "User does not have permission to perform this action" and I did run command as "Administrator"